# How to lock charts to rows and hide those charts with rows when the rows are filtered out?

Tags: excel

Title, basically. I have charts that are moving (even when "Don't move or size with cells" is checked) whenever I filter my data. I want to lock those charts to specific rows so that when those rows are filtered out, so are the charts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Don't move or size with cells` generally works as advertised.  It locks the chart to a fixed `Top/Left` position and does not allow the chart to be affected by what's going on in the underlying Worksheet.

If you want it to be hidden when you filter (this is `size with cells` part), then you need to use `Move and size with cells`.  That is the only option that will hide the chart when the rows are filtered.

Unfortunately you cannot have this one both ways.

Comment: Yep. I gave up and just used chart sheets. Thanks anyways!